# Server-side login prompt box

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, prompt

When I log into my router's firmware, for example, I get a prompt box for the username and password, How is this done? As far as I can tell, JavaScript's `prompt()` only returns one value.. I know it must be server side because the page continues to "load" until I close the box. I also cannot switch tabs in my browser until the box is closed.

Is it possible to do something like this with PHP? How is this done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its done using Basic HTTP Authentication, for this you need to create a user/password file and tell the server that a folder needs to use the Basic HTTP Authentication. This can be done in the server config or in a .htaccess

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this page of the PHP docs - [HTTP authentication with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

Here is the sample code that they give:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>
```

Basically, all you need to do is send the correct headers and the client's browser will be in charge of rendering a native popup with the correct fields.

Once the user has submitted the details your code can validate the login however you want using the `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` variables.

Answer (score 2):

With `Apache` as a web server, you could do that with **[htaccess password protection](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/)**

The protocol is called **[http basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)**